# How to force migrations to a DB if some tables already exist in Django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, migrate

I have a Python/Django proyect. Due to some rolls back, and other mixed stuff we ended up in a kind of odd scenario.

The current scenario is like this:

- DB has the correct tables
- DB can't be rolled back or dropped
- Code is up to date
- Migrations folder is ***behind*** the DB by one or two migrations. (These migrations were applied from somewhere else and that "somewhere else" doesn't exist anymore)
- I add and alter some models
- I run *makemigrations*
- New migrations are created, but it's a mix of new tables and some tables that already exist in the DB.
- If I run *migrate* it will complain that some of the tables that I'm trying to create already exist.

What I need:

To be able to run the migrations and kind of "ignore" the existing tables and apply the new ones. Or any alternative way to achieve this.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

When you apply a migration, Django inserts a row in a table called `django_migrations`.  That's the only way Django knows which migrations have been applied already and which have not.  So the rows in that table have to match the files in your `migrations` directory.  If you've lost the migration files after they were applied, or done anything else to get things out of sync, you'll have problems.. because the migration numbers in your database refer to different migration files than the ones in your project.

So before you do anything else, you need to bring things back into sync by deleting the `django_migrations` table rows for any migration files that you've lost somehow and can't get back.  **The table should contain rows for only those migrations that you do have and that were actually applied to the database correctly**.

Now you need to deal with any changes in your database that Django Migrations doesn't know about.. and for that there are a few options:

If things worked out such that the database changes that were already applied to the database are in different migration files than the ones that weren't, then you can fix it by running your migrations one at a time using the `--fake` option on any changes that are in reality already in the database.  The fake option just writes the row to the `django_migrations` table marking the migration as done.  Only do this if the database does in fact already have all the changes contained in that migration file.

And those migration files that contain only changes which have not been applied to the database, run without the `--fake` option and Django will apply them. eg:

```
# database already has it
manage.py migrate myapp 0003 --fake 
# need it
manage.py migrate myapp 0004
# database already has it
manage.py migrate myapp 0005 --fake
```

If you have migration files where some but not all of the changes have been applied, then you have a bigger problem.  In that case, there are several ways to go about it (choose ONLY ONE):

1. Edit the migration files to put changes that have already been applied (whether Django did it or you did it manually does not matter) into lower number migrations, and put everything you need done into higher numbered files.  Now you can `--fake` the lower number ones, and run the higher numbered ones as normal.  Let's say you have 10 changes you made to your models, and 5 of those changes are actually in the database already, but Django doesn't know about them.. so when you run `makemigrations`, a new migration is created with all 10 changes.  This will normally fail because the database server can't for example add a column that already exists.  Move these already-applied changes out of your new migration file, into the previous (already applied) migration file.  Django will then assume that these were applied with the previous migration and will not try to apply them again.  You can then `migrate` as normal and the new changes will be applied.

   If you don't want to touch your older migration file, a cleaner way to do this is to first run `makemigrations --empty appname` to create an empty migration file.  Then run `makemigrations` which will create another migration with all the changes that Django thinks need to be done.  Move the already done migrations from that file into the empty migration you created.. then `--fake` that one.  This will put Django's understanding of what the database looks like will be in sync with reality and you can then `migrate` as normal, applying the changes in the last migration file.
2. Get rid of any new migrations you just created using makemigrations.  Now, comment out or put back anything in your models that has not been applied to the database, leaving your code matching what's actually in the database.  Now you can do `makemigrations` and `migrate appname --fake` and you will get things back in sync.  Then uncomment your new code and run 'makemigrations' then `migrate` as normal and the changes will be applied.  If the changes are small (for example, adding a few fields), sometimes this is easiest.  If the changes are large, it isn't....
3. You can go ahead and (carefully) make the database changes yourself, bringing the database up to date.  Now just run `migrate --fake` and if you didn't mess up then everything will be ok.  Again, this is easy for smaller changes, not as easy for complicated ones.
4. You can run `manage.py sqlmigrate > mychanges.sql`.  This generates `mychanges.sql` containing all the SQL Django WOULD have executed against the database.  Now edit that file to remove any changes that have already been applied, leaving what needs to be done.  Execute that SQL using `pgadmin` or `psql` (you're using postgresql I hope). Now the changes have all been made.. so you can run `manage.py migrate --fake`, this will bring Django into sync with reality and you should be all set.  If your SQL skills are sufficient, this is probably the most straightforward solution.

I should add two warnings:

First, if you apply a later migration, eg 0003_foobar.py, and then things don't work out and you decide to try going back and apply 0002_bazbuz.py, then Django will TAKE STUFF OUT OF YOUR DATABASE.  For example a column you might have added in 0003 will be dropped along with its data.  Since you say you can't lose data, be very careful about going back.

Second, do not rush into running `--fake` migrations.  Make sure that the entire migration you are about to fake is actually in the database already.  Else it gets very confusing.  If you do regret faking migrations and don't want to roll back, you can erase django's knowledge of the faked migration by deleting that row from the `django_migrations` table.  It is ok to do this.. if you understand what you are doing.  If you know that the migration really was not applied, then it's ok.

Comment: GIves more clarity, you could write a blog that will help more people.

Comment: Life saver. This should be part of the official docs. I can't tell you how many run into issues with migrations. For me, if I wasn't a daily SQL driver, I would have a much harder time. Thanks!

Comment: Option 2 is brilliant!

Answer (score 33):

This blog post really nails it. https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html

Let me summarize the steps in his scenario 2 (you have a production database and want to change schema/models in one or more apps). In my case, I had two apps, queue and routingslip, that had model modifications that I needed to apply to a production system. Key was I already had the database, so this is where --fake-initial comes into play.

Here are the steps I followed. As always, backup everything before starting. I do work in a VM so I just took a snapshot before going forward.

1) Remove the migration history for each app.

```
python manage.py migrate --fake queue zero
python manage.py migrate --fake routingslip zero
```

2) Blow away any migration files *in the entire project within which the app(s) reside*.

```
find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete
find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc"  -delete
```

3) Make migrations

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

4) Apply the migrations, faking initial because the database already exists and we just want the changes:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```

Worked great for me.

Comment: Deleting all your migrations and starting over works fine if you have a simple database with very little history.  But if you have a database which has been built up over time and want to be able to for example restore old database backups, you are going to have problems doing that if you blow away your migration history

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any migration files or you lost the previous file and want to migrate new changes, then you need to follow the following steps carefully:

```
# To create a new migration file before changing the models. 
cmd: python manage.py makemigrations app_name

# Fake migrate
cmd: python manage.py migrate app_name 0005 --fake #[0005 is the migration file number created just now. It'll seem like 0005_add_address or something like this.]

# To create a new migration file after changing the models.
cmd: python manage.py makemigrations app_name

# database already has it
cmd: python manage.py migrate app_name 0006 #[0006 is the migration file number created just now.]
```